# Is there tool for automatic apply new scripts for SQL Server, that locate in some folder?

Tags: sql-server

Is there tool for automatic apply new scripts for SQL Server, that locate in some folder? Thanks.

Comment: Not quite what you're asking, but if you're asking about versioning your database schema you should really look at Migrator.NET or similar - it's great. If you really just want to run scripts you can probably rig something up with osql, the command-line tool included with SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [SSW SQL Deploy](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/SQLDeploy/) to execute a collection of scripts from a folder on your disk against a SQL Server?

[image]